# Obfuscate links in Wordpress (for SEO purpose)

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, seo, obfuscation

Link obfuscation is a more and more common topic in order to improve SEO by masking the non-important links to provide more weight to others.

I'm looking for an efficient way to obfuscate links in Wordpress, directly in the source code obviously, for example by adding a special class to my links.

It must turn the `<a>` element into something else like a `<span>`, with no more visible *href* attribute nor any actual URL, so that robots cannot see any link.

It must be done **before** rendering the source code, not overridden in JavaScript.

Example :

`<a href="https://example.com">Hello</a>`

turns into :

`<span data-o="CRYPTEDLINK">Hello</span>`

then some JS allows click on the element to redirect to the original link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making my own system that allows me to obfuscate any link easily.

Add the following code to your child theme's *functions.php* file, then just add the class "obfuscate" to any  element to obfuscate its link by replacing it with a  element with no readable link.

Also be sure to edit styles above, or delet them and style the "akn-obf-link" class in your own CSS file, so that it looks like a link to the visitor.

```
<?php

/**************************************************************************************\
|* Links obfuscation - add class "obfuscate" to any <a> element to obfuscate its link *|
\**************************************************************************************/

// Add this code to your child theme's functions.php file, then just add the class "obfuscate" to any <a> element to obfuscate its link by replacing it with a <span> element with no readable link.
// The obfuscated elements inherits the original <a> element's classes, along with a "akn-obf-link" class, so you might need to add CSS to style the "akn-obf-link" class so that it looks like a link to the visitor, maybe at least to add a cursor:pointer.
// On right click, the obfuscated link will be wrapped with a proper <a> element with the "akn-deobf-link" for a brief moment, so that a proper context menu appears, you can remove that behaviour by setting the "deobfuscate_on_right_click" option to false in the code bellow.

// Edit 2022-04-05 - modified regex to allow for html elements and new lines into the <a> element, modified callback so the obfuscated element inherits the original link's classes, modified JS to add mousewheel click and right click options.

// Edit 2023-01-26 - greatly improved regex thanks to @MadMaxInfinity on Stack Overflow, it now both allows more matches in different scenarios and returns less false positives matches, more infos on his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75234749/2498324

// Edit 2023-02-08 - improved class regex thanks to @MadMaxInfinity on Stack Overflow again.

add_action('wp_loaded', 'buffer_start');
function buffer_start() {
    ob_start('akn_ofbuscate_buffer');
}
add_action('shutdown', 'buffer_end');
function buffer_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
}
function akn_ofbuscate_buffer($buffer) {
    $result = preg_replace_callback('#<a[^>]+((?<=\s)href=(\"|\')([^\"\']*)(\'|\")[^>]+(?<=\s)class=(\"|\')[^\'\"]*(?<!\w|-)obfuscate(?!\w|-)[^\'\"]*(\"|\')|(?<=\s)class=(\"|\')[^\'\"]*(?<!\w|-)obfuscate(?!\w|-)[^\'\"]*(\"|\')[^>]+(?<=\s)href=(\"|\')([^\"\']*)(\'|\"))[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>#miUs', function($matches) {
        preg_match('#<a[^>]+(?<=\s)class=[\"|\\\']([^\\\'\"]+)[\"|\\\']#imUs',$matches[0],$matches_classes);
        $classes = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',str_replace('obfuscate','',$matches_classes[1])));
        return '<span class="akn-obf-link'.($classes?' '.$classes:'').'" data-o="'.base64_encode($matches[3]?:$matches[10]).'" data-b="'.((strpos(strtolower($matches[0]),'_blank')!==false)?'1':'0').'">'.$matches[12].'</span>';
    }, $buffer);
    return $result;
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'akn_ofbuscate_footer_js');
function akn_ofbuscate_footer_js() {
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                // options you can change
                var deobfuscate_on_right_click = true;
                // function to open link on click
                function akn_ofbuscate_clicked($el,force_blank) {
                    if (typeof(force_blank)=='undefined')
                        var force_blank = false;
                    var link = atob($el.data('o'));
                    var _blank = $el.data('b');
                    if (_blank || force_blank)
                        window.open(link);
                    else
                        location.href = link;
                }
                // trigger link opening on click
                $(document).on('click','.akn-obf-link',function() {
                    var $el = $(this);
                    if (!$el.closest('.akn-deobf-link').length)
                        akn_ofbuscate_clicked($el);
                });
                // trigger link openin in new tab on mousewheel click
                $(document).on('mousedown','.akn-obf-link',function(e) {
                    if (e.which==2) {
                        var $el = $(this);
                        if (!$el.closest('.akn-deobf-link').length) {
                            akn_ofbuscate_clicked($el,true);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                });
                // deobfuscate link on right click so the context menu is a legit menu with link options
                $(document).on('contextmenu','.akn-obf-link',function(e) {
                    if (deobfuscate_on_right_click) {
                        var $el = $(this);
                        if (!$el.closest('.akn-deobf-link').length) {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            var link = atob($el.data('o'));
                            var _blank = $el.data('b');
                            $el.wrap('<a class="akn-deobf-link" href="'+link+'"'+(_blank?' target="_BLANK"':'')+'></a>').parent().trigger('contextmenu');
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $el.unwrap();
                            },10);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

I'm also sharing the code on this Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/cXEBSVFn

Consider checking the link just in case I updated the code on it and forgot to update it here

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to modify the "detection" regular expression used with `preg_replace_callback`.

First of all, you may add a question mark right after the group between the tags as a link having no text is valid according to W3C validator i.e. `<a href=...></a>`.

A second suggestion is to add `(?<!\w|-)` before and `(?!\w|-)` after the class name to detect. Otherwise, you get false detections with class names like `do-not-obfuscate_this` or `notobfuscated`.

My third suggestion is to add `(?<=\s)` before each `href` and `class` word. To avoid matching custom attributes like `data-href=` or `unclassify=`.

My last suggestion is to remove `(?!<a)` from the end as the expression is non greedy (and nesting `<a>` tags *-the idea between this?-* is not allowed). Thus, `(.+(?!<a))<\/a>` should become `(.+)<\/a>`. And this, as it should be combined to the suggestion one, should lead us to `(.*)<\/a>` (no need for `(.+)?<\/a>`).

Finaly, the regular expression I use is:

`'#<a[^>]+((?<=\s)href=(\"|\')([^\"\']*)(\'|\")[^>]+(?<=\s)class=(\"|\')[^\'\"]*(?<!\w|-)obfuscate(?!\w|-)[^\'\"]*(\"|\')|(?<=\s)class=(\"|\')[^\'\"]*(?<!\w|-)obfuscate(?!\w|-)[^\'\"]*(\"|\')[^>]+(?<=\s)href=(\"|\')([^\"\']*)(\'|\"))[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>#miUs'`

You may be interested in checking the differences between [your regexp](https://regex101.com/r/msDuKs/1) and [mine](https://regex101.com/r/xGSgou/1) (check the unit tests).

Comment: One more thing I add to change:
`preg_match('#<a[^>]+class=[\"|\\\']([^\\\'\"]+)[\"|\\\']#imUs',$matches[0],$matches_classes);`
should be :
`preg_match('#<a[^>]+(?<=\s)class=[\"|\\\']([^\\\'\"]+)[\"|\\\']#imUs',$matches[0],$matches_classes);`
to avoid matching things like "internalclass=" when looking for the classes.

Comment: Hey @MadMaxInfinity, do you think it could be possible to have another regex that matches any <a> tag that is included inside any tag that has the "obfuscate" class? That would be amazing for example in menus where WP only allows to add a custom class to a parent of the <a> and not the <a> itself.

Comment: Hello @rAthus : it may be possible, of course, but it would lead to very complex things.
I think you’d better use some hook like those discussed ere: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235880/using-filters-to-change-href-of-nav-menu-page-link